# How to extract all the hrefs and src inside specific divs with beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to extract all the href and src inside all the divs on the page that have class = 'news_item'

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="col">
<div class="group">
<h4>News</h4>
<div class="news_item">

<a href="www.link.com">

<h2 class="link">
here is a link-heading
</h2>
<div class="Img">
<img border="0" src="/image/link" />
</div>
<p></p>
</a>
</div>
```

from here what I want to extract is:

**www.link.com , here is the link-heading and /image/link**

My code is:

```
 def scrape_a(url):

        news_links = soup.select("div.news_item [href]")
        for links in news_links:
          if news_links:
            return 'http://www.web.com' + news_links['href']

    def scrape_headings(url):
        for news_headings in soup.select("h2.link"):
          return str(news_headings.string.strip())


    def scrape_images(url):
        images = soup.select("div.Img[src]")
        for image in images:
          if images:
            return 'http://www.web.com' + news_links['src']


    def top_stories():


    r = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
  link = scrape_a(soup)
  heading = scrape_headings(soup)
  image = scrape_images(soup)
  message = {'heading': heading, 'link': link, 'image': image}
  print message
```

The problem is that it gives me error:

```
    **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable**
```

Here is the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web_parser.py", line 40, in <module>
    top_stories()
  File "web_parser.py", line 32, in top_stories
    link = scrape_a('www.link.com')
  File "web_parser.py", line 10, in scrape_a
    news_links = soup.select_all("div.news_item [href]")
```

Comment: Please paste the stack traceback

Comment: @hjpotter92 done, please see the post again

Comment: And what is `div.news_item [href]` supposed to match/find?

Comment: do this r = requests.get(url) just once and pass r.content to your methods

Comment: As I wrote earlier it is supposed to find www.link.com inside <a href="www.link.com">

Comment: Did that already, see the code above

Comment: I mean you hammer the site three times, but you just need it once: soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content) and use soup then everywhere

Comment: except the fact, that there are no news_item divs on web.com ...you need something like soup_news_item = soup.select("div.news_item") and then soup_news_item.find_all('a', href=True)

Comment: I have tried this earlier as well seems to be that find_all does not work: trace back of the error File "web_parser.py", line 28, in top_stories
    link = scrape_a(soup)
  File "web_parser.py", line 8, in scrape_a
    links = news_links.find_All('a', href=True)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: for x in soup_news_item

Comment: nope not even that same error as above:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be grabbing all of the news items at once and then iterating through them. This makes it easy to organize the data that you get into manageable chunks (in this case dicts). Try something like this

```
url = "http://www.web.com"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

messages = []

news_links = soup.select("div.news_item") # selects all .news_item's
for l in news_links:
    message = {}
    message['heading'] = l.find("h2").text.strip()

    link = l.find("a")
    if not link:
        continue
    message['link'] = link['href']
    
    image = l.find('img')
    if not image:
        continue
    message['image'] = "http://www.web.com{}".format(image['src'])

    messages.append(message)

print messages
```

Comment: Thank you I think this is the closest to answering my question though I stil get this error:  File "web_parser.py", line 22
    message['image'] = 'http://www.web.com{}".format(image_src)
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Yep that's because I used a single quote to open the string and a double quote to close it. It should work now.

Comment: Returns a none type object: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web_parser.py", line 20, in <module>
    message['link'] = l.find("a")["href"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: That means that there is a `.news_item` that doesn't have an `a` tag. I've updated my answer to just skip these divs.

Comment: With a slight change to message['image'] = "http://www.web.com{}".format(image['src']) it works now :)

Comment: Haha yeah I noticed that right before you commented. Glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 1):

Most of your errors come from the fact that the `news_link` is not being found properly.  You aren't getting back the `tag` you expect.

Change:

```
    news_links = soup.select("div.news_item [href]")
    for links in news_links:
      if news_links:
        return 'http://www.web.com' + news_links['href']
```

to this and see if it helps:

```
    news_links = soup.find_all("div", class="news_item")
    for links in news_links:
         if news_links:
               return 'http://www.web.com' + news_links.find("a").get('href')
```

Also note that the return statement will give you something like http://www.web.comwww.link.com  which I don't think you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea to split the tasks into different methods is pretty good -
nice to read, to change and to reuse.

The errors are almost solved and fixed, in the trace there is *select_all* but its not in beautifulsoup and neither in your code and some other stuff ...long story short I would do it like this.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urljoin
import requests


def news_links(url, soup):
    links = []
    for text in soup.select("div.news_item"):
        for x in text.find_all(href=True):
            links.append(urljoin(url, x['href']))
    return links


def news_headings(soup):
    headings = []
    for news_headings in soup.select("h2.link"):
        heading.append(str(news_headings.string.strip()))
    return headings


def news_images(url, soup):
    sources = []
    for image in soup.select("img[src]"):
        sources.append(urljoin(url, image['src']))
    return sources


def top_stories():
    url = 'http://www.web.com/'
    r = requests.get(url)
    content = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    message = {'heading': news_headings(soup),
               'link': news_links(url, soup),
               'image': news_images(url, soup)}
    return message


print top_stories()
```

Soup is robust, you want to find or select something that is not there it returns an empty list. It looks like you parsing a list of items - the code is pretty close to be used for this.